# Broken theme, icons and shortcuts

Tags: desktop, themes

So I logged in and this is what I have. I don't have any clue why this happening.
The GTK theme are like Adwaita, the icons are Adwaita too, the shortucts don't work...

[image]

...even that Debian logo is weird

[image]

EDIT: ok i actually ran io.elementary.onboarding before i restarted it, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I explained this on Facebook group. https://www.facebook.com/groups/elementary.talk/permalink/1901761249958898/?app=fbl

So, as you can see it depends on what set you are using. You can change the logo in set by replace file.